# Need Help: Stack ADT Linked list with VOID STAR implementation (C Programming)

Tags: c, pointers, stack, void

First of all, i couldn't use "code sample" therefore i am adding my codes as stated below:

**Header.h**

```
    #ifndef MYHEADER_H
    #define MYHEADER_H

    #define EMPTY_TOS -1
    #define MIN_STACK_SIZE 5
    #define FALSE 0
    #define TRUE 1


    struct Node;
    typedef struct Node *Stack;


    void *PopStack(Stack);
    void *TopOfStack(Stack);
    void PushStack(void *val, Stack); 
    int IsEmptyStack(Stack);
    int IsFullStack(Stack);

    #endif
```

**Header.c**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include "myheader.h"

    #define EMPTY_TOS -1 
    #define MIN_STACK_SIZE 5
    #define FALSE 0
    #define TRUE 1

    struct Node
    {
        void *val; 
        struct Node *next;
    };

    void PushStack(void *x, Stack s)
    {
         printf("/n a1");
        struct Node *insert;
               printf("/n a2");
        insert = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
               printf("/n a3");

        if (insert == NULL)
               printf("Out of memory space!\n");
        else
        {      printf("\n a4");
               insert->val = x;printf("\n a5");
               insert->next= s;printf("\n a6");
               s = insert;printf("\n a7");
        }
        printf("\n a8");
    }

    void *PopStack(Stack s)
    {                    printf("\n pop1");
        struct Node *remove; printf("\n pop2");
        void *val;           printf("\n pop3");

        if (IsEmptyStack(s))
        {
               printf("\nThe stack is empty!\n");
        }
        else   
        {      printf("\n pop4");
               remove = s;       printf("\n pop5");
               val = remove->val;     printf("\n pop67");
               s = s->next;      printf("\n pop7");
               free(remove);     printf("\n pop8");
        }
        return val;              printf("\n pop9");
    }

    void *TopOfStack(Stack s)
    {
        if (!IsEmptyStack(s))
               return s->next->val;
        else
        {
               printf("\nThe stack is empty\n");
               return 0;
        }

    }

    int IsEmptyStack(Stack s)
    {
        printf("empty");
        return (s == NULL);
    }


    int IsFullStack(Stack s)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
```

**Project.cpp**

```
int main()
{

 Stack S = NULL;
 int x = 5;
 PushStack((void *)x, S);
 int z = (int)PopStack(S);
 printf("\n z = %d \n", z);



 system("PAUSE");
 return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I want to put X, into S(tack) by using PushStack function. And then i want to take the value(5) stored in S and print it as Z which is an integer. But i see a numbers like 4247612, which does not change as long as the compiler window is not closed.

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you can (1) be more specific about what you expect that is not happening (2) any error messages or unexpected/unexplained output (3) localize the problem to a more limited portion of your code.

Comment: You need to start with a good beginners' tutorial.  It's impossible to ask a question in an understandable way until you at least learn the terminology for such essential features of C as pointers.

Comment: @dmckee & @Ben Vogit: I edited my question.

Comment: Much better. Thanks. BTW--Ben won't get automatically notified of your comment because the notifier only supports one @ reference per comment.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `PushStack((void *)x, S); int z = (int)PopStack(S);` can incur truncation, and so, puncasting types like this is not guaranteed to work in all cases: `void *` is not a magic type that can hold each and every possible value in the universe. (It would especially go up in flames if you started to use `double`s instead of `int`s on contemporary implementations.) It may however point to one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've defined `Stack` as a `struct Node *` and are trying to update its value inside the `PushStack()` and `PopStack()` functions. When you assign a value to `s` inside either function, it only updates the local variable, and not `S` in your main function. Instead, `PushStack()` and `PopStack()` may need to take a pointer to a stack object (`Stack *`) so that you can update the caller's value too.

Answer (score 0):

Your `PushStack` and `PopStack` routines is not doing what you want

To exhibit it explicitly in the `PopStack` function:

```
void *PopStack(Stack s) { // <-- The s declared here is a LOCAL copy of the s your pass
  struct Node *remove;
  void *val;

  if (IsEmptyStack(s)) {
    printf("\nThe stack is empty!\n");
  } else {
    remove = s; 
    val = remove->val; 
    s = s->next;          // <-- Changes the local copy, but the original is unchanged
    free(remove);   
  }
  return val; 
}
```

Because the `S` in main is never updated it continues to be NULL.

You would fix this by passing a `Stack *s`, and accessing it using `*s` in both function.

Comment: I fixed that and it works properly now. Thank you for your help :)